# Running multiple mobile phones on aws device farm for android espresso tests

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-espresso, aws-device-farm

We are using `aws device farm` for android espresso testing. Initially we were running single phone device and all my tests were passing. Now we are running tests on multiple devices, and `Login test` is just passing on a single device, and failing on rest.

The issue is all the devices are a using common database to authenticate the `pin_code` which gets reset to `NULL` after you enter it. So the `Login Test` will only pass for a single device which enters the pin_code first. See the below image for more clarity:-

[image]

Few Questions:-

1- Is there any way in `aws device farm` through which I can configure the phones to use different instances of database?

2- How should we handle this issue? Could you suggest me some ideas to work on?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a lightweight http server as your "test configuration" server. When you test launches, it could contact this server and fetch the configuration like database or other info, then execute your test based on the information.

Comment: We need to fetch the `username` and `pin_code` from our project database so this suggestion will not work.

Comment: Why? Do you mean you want to use same username and pin_code for all your tests? Even that, as you mentioned in question, you could return different database instances as test configuration.